# Rounding off an integer to always end on 0

Tags: c

I'm making a program to calculate the number of perfect squares between 1 and another number, and I want the counter to take only the first number of the integer, and put 0 on the rest, e.g: Result of the calculation is 31, I want to display 30, if it's 190, then display 100, and so on.

```
int number;
int i = 1;
int perfectCounter = 0;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);

while (i <= number) {
    float tempSquare = sqrt(i);
    int integerPart = tempSquare;

    if (tempSquare == integerPart)
       perfectCounter++;

    i++;
}

printf("%d", perfectCounter);
```

That's the code that I have right now, if I insert 1000, it will display 31, and I want it to display 30, I can't think a solution for this.

Comment: Use logarithms to find out the highest power of 10 in the number. Divide by that power of 10, get the integer part of that, and multiply by the power of 10.

Comment: This is no high school algebra, you just have to translate it to the analogous C functions.

Comment: `if ( tempSquare == integerPart )` may fail due to floating point rounding; it would be more precise to test `if ( integerPart * integerPart == i )`

Comment: @M.M: Certainly true. On the other hand, the net effect of the loop is to compute `floor(sqrt(n))`, which doesn't require any testing at all.

Comment: "the first number of the integer"... Ehm, an integer **is** a single number! You seem to mean a **digit**. Please try to be clear when asking. You will also notice it helps for programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the number by the highest power of 10 below the number. Do this using integer arithmetic, so it gets the integer part of the division. Then multiply by the power of 10.

```
#include <math.h>

int powerOf10 = pow(10, (int)log10(perfectCounter));
int roundedCounter = (perfectCounter/powerOf10)*powerOf10;
printf("%d", roundedCounter);
```

Comment: Even with the modern math co-processors the integer arithmetic is still vastly faster than floating-point.

Comment: So what? Who cares how long it takes to round off the final result. We're not doing this inside a big loop.

Comment: And people complain that modern software is bloated and slow ;-) However you do have a valid point that shorter code is easier to read.

Comment: touché :) I think my background in high-performance systems is skewing my point of view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function like this one to round your numbers. Basically what it does is it "chips away" one digit at a time until we are left with only one digit and then adds appropriate number of zeros to it:

```
int round(int _in){
    int numDigits = 0;
    while(_in > 9){
        ++numDigits;
        _in /= 10;
    }
    int res = _in;  // whatever is left would be the left-most digit
    for(int i = 0; i < numDigits; ++i){
        res *= 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution with no math:

```
void print_rounded(int i) {
  unsigned u = i;
  if (i < 0) { putchar('-'); u = -i; }
  char buf[2];
  int n = snprintf(buf, 2, "%u", u);
  for (putchar(buf[0]); --n; putchar('0')) {}
}
```

(In other words, print the first digit, and then print enough 0's to make up the length of the original number.)